# How to set custom name for android language directory?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to have different directories for multiple languages. For example I have Kurdish language with 2 dialects - Badini and Sorani. But there are no specific regions for them in Android.

[image]

Can I name them customly for each region?

**Correct dir naming for Kurdish but one dir for all regions - not desired**

[image]

**Inorrect naming but desired one**

While building throws `Error: Invalid resource directory name`

[image]

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In one word NO,

According to google documentation To add support for more locales, create additional directories inside res/. Each directory's name should adhere to the following format:

```
<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
```

After you’ve decided on the locales to support, create the resource subdirectories and files.
For example, values-b+es/ contains string resources for locales with the language code es. Similarly, mipmap-b+es+ES/ contains icons for locales with the es language code and the ES country code. Android loads the appropriate resources according to the locale settings of the device at runtime.

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-b+es/
           strings.xml
       mipmap/
           country_flag.png
       mipmap-b+es+ES/
           country_flag.png
```

for more details follow the document [language](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that :) What I am looking for is some possible workaround for this.